# Swift: UISearchController bug content behind navigation bar after pushing view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

There is a very weird bug when I push a control to navigation controller and when I return back, look at the gif below.

Before push the detail view controller
[image]

After click on back button from detail view controller
[image]

My code:

```
searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.searchBar.placeholder = Localizations.searching
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
searchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = true

viewController.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
viewController.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
viewController.definesPresentationContext = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the moment I have found a solution but that looks bad.

After push the viewcontroller I must run this:

```
        let searchedText = searchController.searchBar.text
        searchController.isActive = false
        searchController.searchBar.text = searchedText
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same Problem and found a feasible solution:

After you add the TableView to your ViewController, pinn all directions to the safeAreaLayout(or superview)

```
self.view.addSubview(tableView)
tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

And activate `Extend Edges` - `Unter Opaque Bars`

[image]